# error file could not be opened when upload image laravel

Tags: laravel, upload, photo

I am using Storage to upload multi photo to localhost. But I can't view the photo after upload. My orginal photo is 61Kb, but after upload, it is just 6 bytes.
In my Controller:

```
$img=array();
if($files=$req->images){
        foreach($files as $file){
            $name=date('Y-m-d-H:i:s')."-".$file;
            Storage::disk('local')->put('public/product/'.$name, $file, 'public');
            $img[]=$name;
        }
}
ProductImage::insert( [
        'id_detail' =>$ctsanpham->id,
        'image'=>  implode($img),
]);
```

View:

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple="true" accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg">
```

Notification:

[image]

Comment: @NguyenVanTai you can use `http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation` library. this provide multiple options related to images.

Comment: Thank you so much! but I try to find a simple way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solve my problem.
I forget putting method="post" in Form and method post in Route
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use either of [`FilesystemAdapter::putFile`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L191) or [`FilesystemAdapter::putFileAs`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L205) when using an instance of `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`. *e.g.*

```
 $options = ['visibility' => 'public'];
 Storage::disk('local')
     ->putFileAs('public/product', $file, $name, $options);
```

If doing so using `FilesystemAdapter::put`, you need to first stream contents of the `UploadedFile` to string then *put* it. 
`FileSystemAdapter::putFileAs` takes care of this for you.

Comment: Can I use $file->move(' ',$); ?
And if I can, how can I use it?

Comment: I just use that code. But, I got a error
Call to a member function getRealPath() on string